# form has many rows, how to reference each row in my action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have many rows that I display on a page, and each row has a textbox with a user entered value in it.

When the user submits the form, I have take each row's textbox value, and do some db work on them.

The db work is performing updates, so I have to be able to reference the ID of the row also (which I have to store somewhere??)

what are my options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`name` of the input(s)](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_name.asp) correctly. The Action won't see which "row" is associated with the value, nor will it see the `id`. It will only see the `name`.

Comment: It was my understanding that, in the absence of the name attribute, MVC would use the 'id' in order to set the object value of the model that's being bound. Is this not correct?

Comment: Dan, that's wrong. You may be thinking of the fact that `Html.TextBox` and the like set *both* the `id` and the `name`. But MVC isn't even involved here. The *browser* will send the `name` and ignore the `id` (if any) when submitting a form. If there's no `name`, then the element won't be sent, period.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) method isn't exactly 'nice', it would work for what I believe you may want.

Comment: I like this article, but it is out of date, so I wrote mine: http://caughtintoacameltrap.blogspot.com/2009/12/aspnet-binding-model-to-list.html

Comment: Hey. I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what differences your article makes to the one by Phil Haack. They both show the same way of model binding. Also, I commented on your post with a nicer way of doing foreach loops that require an index - `Model.Select((x, i)=> new { Current = x, Index = i })`.

Comment: @Dan Atkinson: Thanks for comment. My solution doesn't define hidden field with `products.Index` name. It is not needed anymore. Indexing from 0 is enough.